# Opencart PHP Notice; Undefine variable: Username

Tags: php, opencart

I am using Opencart Version 2.3.0.2 and I am getting an error log with:

```
PHP Notice: Undefined variable: username in
2016-09-08 12:53:35 - PHP Notice: Undefined variable: username in /home/sitename/public_html/storename/admin/view/template/common/column_left.tpl on line 5;
```

**Can I assume the following statement is correct;**

The reason why it's undefined is because it hasn't been set in the controller file first.

Opencart uses the MVC architecture, varibles are defined in the Controller, then used within the Template / View files. For this reason, it will always evaluate false using `isset()`

variable `$username` is not set,

The code missing from the controller file (located: `admin/controller/common/column_left.php`) would be:

```
if (isset($username)) 
    $this->data['username'] = $this->config->get('username');
```

Comment: This is definitely a bug.  It appears to be fixed in the latest unreleased build - you can probably drop it in as a replacement: https://github.com/opencart/opencart/blob/master/upload/admin/controller/common/column_left.php

Comment: Thanks, I'll chk it out

Comment: I uploaded the version in github and still get the same error.  I put both files side by side and couldn't find anything different.  I also did the modifications as I wrote above and nothing happens.  Still get the same error.   Any other suggestions?

Comment: Found that my VQMod was not working properly and try different version, but then used Integrated VQmod for OpenCart 2 from  JNeuhoff and that corrected the issue.  Link to extension http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=19501

Answer (score 0):

updating the code Line no. 5 in `admin/view/template/common/column_left.tpl` as given below

```html
<img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" alt="<?php echo $firstname; ?> <?php echo $lastname; ?>" title="<?php echo $firstname; ?> <?php echo $lastname; ?>" class="img-circle" />
```

https://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?p=637581

Comment: Try not to use the snippet for non-working code, use a code block instead.